# Поиск части вектора в векторе

Tags: c++, поиск, vector, c++14

Для `std::string` есть команда [`rfind`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/rfind/), а есть ли что-то для векторов?

Мне нужно найти подвектор в векторе справа налево, как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например  так

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<string> v1 = {"A","B","C"};
    vector<string> v3 = {"A","C","C"};
    vector<string> v2 = {"X","Y","A","B","C","D"};

    auto res = search(begin(v2), end(v2), begin(v1), end(v1));
    auto found = res != end(v2);
    cout << boolalpha << found;

    auto res2 = search(begin(v2), end(v2), begin(v3), end(v3));
    auto found2 = res2 != end(v2);
    cout << boolalpha << found2;


    return 0;
}
```

Справа - налево: переворачиваем список, в котором ищем.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<string> v1 = { "A","B","C" };
    vector<string> v2 = { "X","Y","M","C","B","A" };
    reverse(begin(v2), end(v2));
    auto res = search(begin(v2), end(v2), begin(v1), end(v1));
    auto found = res != end(v2);
    cout << boolalpha << found << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

upd:

Если вам нужно искать вхождение с конца, то можно просто перевернуть оба вектора, найти вхождение и получить позицию в исходном векторе.

Пример:

1. Исходный вектор `a` = `A, B, C, D, A, B`. Ищем - `b` = `A, B`
2. Переворачиваем вектора. `a` = `B, A, D, C, B, A`. Ищем `b` = `B, A`
3. Ищем вхождение `b` в `a` - позиции `0` и `4`
4. Определяем перевод позиции перевернутого вектора в позицию не в перевернутом векторе по формуле `pos(T) = len(T) - pos(R) - len(S)`, где `pos(T)` - позиция в искомом векторе, `len(T)` - длинна этого же вектора, `pos(R)` - позиция в перевернутом векторе, `len(S)` - длинна искомого вектора.
5. `0` -> `4`, `4` -> `0`

Comment: Спасибо, а я все голову ломал....

Comment: А этот поиск точно ищет справа налево?

Comment: @AlrottSlimRG Для того, чтобы искать справа налево - переверните вектор через `reverse`

Comment: Не покажите, как?

Comment: @AlrottSlimRG обновил. Если я, конечно, правильно понял, что вы имеете в виду под справа-налево

Comment: Нет, я имел ввиду, если есть огромный вектор, к которому где-то в конце добавили `abc` и поиск должен начинаться с справа и идти влево

Comment: Т.е. если мы ищем в `{'a','b','c','a','b','c'}` вектор `{'a','b'}` то поиск должен вывести `3`, а не `0`

Comment: @AlrottSlimRG переворачиваете оба вектора, ищите первое вхождение - получаете позицию m. Чтобы узнать позицию в исходном (не перевернутом) списке берите позицию k = n - m - (длинна искомого вектора), где n - длинна вектора

Comment: Огромное спасибо

Comment: Не уверен, что на практике крутить вектора (потом наверное обратно их надо будет раскрутить) ради использования search() эффективно. Может лучше просто, руками? (всей писанины -- 2 вложенных  цикла)

Comment: @avp наверное, вы правы) Я ни в коем случае не претендую на оптимальное решение

Comment: @avp можете показать - как?

Comment: @AlrottSlimRG так используйте for с (длинна вектора - длина искомого вектора) вниз, а там на каждую итерацию проверяйте соответствие вектору